# Error with MATLAB

Tags: macos, java

I regularly use MATLAB from the command-line instead of launching the full graphical user interface. Ever since I made the last update of OS from 10.7.3 -> 10.7.4, I started getting the following errors, whenever I would launch something with a graphical interface within MATLAB:

```
May 17 10:35:40 HOST_NAME MATLAB_maci64[549] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0 
May 17 10:35:40 HOST_NAME MATLAB_maci64[549] <Error>: CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0 
May 17 10:35:40 HOST_NAME MATLAB_maci64[549] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0 
May 17 10:35:40 HOST_NAME MATLAB_maci64[549] <Error>: CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0
```

This is how I usually launch MATLAB from the command line:

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash
```

Recently, I've read of other Java based applications with GUIs having the same problem. Just wondering if there is a quick fix for this.

** This is becoming really annoying, I can't seem to find a solution, I'm using 2011a is anyone seeing this with a more recent version?

Comment: We see the problem too with our Java desktop application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm having this problem with Matlab 2011a on Lion 10.7.4.  But fortunately it seems to be fixed in Matlab 2011b -- no more annoying CGContext errors.

So it's definitely worth it to grab a more recent version of Matlab.